# Why are PWR's being build instead of FBR's or LMFBR's?

Tags: nuclear-physics, power, electrical-engineering, nuclear-engineering

Why are PWR's still being built in modern times when we have the option to use designs that allow intake of raw uranium without the need for enrichment and allow for recycling of waste material.

I don't understand why we would continue to make reactors that need the long enrichment supply chain and only produce unusable nuclear waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast breeder reactors (FBRs) and in particular liquid metal fast breeder reactors (LMFBRs) actually require more fissile material (U-235 or Pu-239) than thermal reactors- pressurized water reactors (PWRS) or boiling water reactors (BWRs)- because the fission cross section of the fissile isotopes is smaller at the higher neutron energies in the fast reactor spectrum than in the thermal energy spectrum.

However, in the higher energy spectrum the reactor can convert more non-fissile uranium (U-238) to fissile material (Pu-239) than it consumes fissile material.  So the fast reactor breeds Pu-239 and allows the 99.3% of U that is non-fissile U-238 to be converted into fissile Pu-239 for use as fuel. Using Pu-239 with natural U as fuel negates the need for enrichment of natural U, but requires reprocessing of the spent fuel to recover the breed Pu-239 from the rest of the radionuclides in the spent fuel for blending with natural U for new fuel.

The problem is that the new fuel with Pu and natural U allows for the Pu to be chemically separated from the U for use in a weapon. Current PWR and BWR fuel contains U enriched in  U-235 which cannot be chemically separated from the U-238.  So, concerns about nuclear proliferation are the major reason large scale commercial use of breeder reactors has not occurred.

In the late 1970's, President Carter in the US stopped development of reprocessing of spent fuel (Barnwell plant in South Carolina) and development of fast breeder reactors (Clinch Breeder Breeder Reactor) due to proliferation of nuclear weapon concerns.  This decision led to shutdown of the fast flux test facility (FFTF) in the US and curtailment of work in the US on the use of breeder reactors.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Could you indicate some sources for those interested in reading more on the subject?

Comment: See online articles about fast breeder reactors; for example, https://www.nuclear-power.net/breeder-reactor/